# AppleTV Air Mirroring: does the signal go through the WIFI router?

Tags: wifi, appletv, streaming, mirroring

A general question about how AirMirroring works, because I've some freezing problems and I would like to know if connecting my Apple TV to the rough by ehternet cable could help.

N.B. I'm not watching online streamed movies, but just using Apple TV for Air Mirroring. The videos are stored on my macbook Air hard disk.

How does Air Mirroring works: is the streaming going from 
macbook ---> Apple TV, or
macbook ---> WIFI Modem ---> Apple TV ?

If the second is true, connecting Apple TV to WIFI Modem could help.. even if the content is not online streaming... ?

Comment: if you stream from Mac/iPad etc. it depends, if you have an icloud account and/or use itunes match  it will stream the movie/audio tracks with the higher quality. in my case these are the one's stored on my mac / expect those i've bought by amazone -> apple also has them in better quality so it goes iCloud/Apple iTunes Server --> AppleTV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different AirPlay devices exist:

- AirPlay transmitters (such as iPhone/iPad/iPod/iTunes)
- AirPlay receivers (Apple TV, AirPort Express and audio system with built-in AirPlay)

Apple TV will connect to your WiFi modem to get Internet access.

It will also connect to your computer (without modem) for Airplay/mirroring.

It could also connect true the [AirPort Express modem if you have it set up for that](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4587). Check what settings do you have in this article.

Comment: True, you don't need internet access, but you still need a modem to connect your ATV and computer on a local network.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused now: if one device connects to another device, then either the rooter (WiFi modem seems to be used here?) or bluetooth must be used - or not?

As far as I know: if you connect your Apple TV to the rooter via Ethernet, then it should be faster. But it depends on the speed of your local (WiFi) and your Ethernet.

If you have a MacBook Air - why do you not connect your TV to it? Using any network (WiFi, Ethernet...) will reduce transfer rate anyway. It seems I missed something?

Comment: Yes, good point: you miss the knowledge of my dining room. I'm using a projector placed on one side of the room, connected to AppleTV. I can't move it somewhere else because I can only project on the opposite wall. On the opposite wall I have the Internet Plug with the Modem. Therefore i can't connect modem to Apple TV. The Macbook Air is with me on the sofa, or table, so it can';t be connected to anything.

Comment: The only option is to buy a long ethernet cable, going from one wall to the other (6,7 meters?). But I'm afraid such long cable might lose a bit of quality.. still better than WIFI though... but I wanted to be sure before to buy.

Comment: but before I will try another modem with 802.11n, because the current one is 802.11b/g.

Comment: I am using a 4m ethernet cable without any problem. It might loose quality aka transfer rate (which I do not see), but still much better than WiFi. Which of course depends on the WiFi / Ethernet protocol of your hardware. Anyway: you could use a repeater if the distance is a problem, but I would give the "simple" Ethernet cable a trial...